# ECO D35 for Game Analysis,- Queen's Gambit Declined: Queen's Knight Variation, 3...Nf6 game for analysis

Tags: analysis, pawns, game-complexity, eco

Queen's Gambit Declined: Queen's Knight Variation, 3...Nf6 game for analysis.

Here is the PGN

```
[fen ""]
[Event "Live Chess"]
[Site "Chess.com"]
[Date "2017.01.17"]
[White "anandsadasivam"]
[Black "RandyDoce"]
[WhiteElo "684"]
[BlackElo "687"]
[TimeControl "600"]
[ECO "D35"]
[Result "1-0"]
[Termination "anandsadasivam won by checkmate"]
[CurrentPosition "5Q1k/2P3p1/8/4P2p/2rPB3/4PN2/PP1K1b2/R1B4q b - - 2 33"]

1.d4 d5 2.c4 Nf6 3.Nc3 e6 4.c5 a5 5.f4 c6 6.h4 Be7 7.Rh3 Ng4 8.e3 Nf6 9.g4 O-O 10.h5 b5 11.g5 e5 12.gxf6 Bxf6 13.fxe5 Bh4+ 14.Kd2 b4 15.Na4 Na6 16.Nf3 Bxh3 17.Bxh3 Rb8 18.Nb6 b3 19.Qxb3 Bf2 20.Bd7 Qh4 21.Bxc6 Qxh5 22.Bxd5 Qh1 23.Qa4 Rbd8 24.Be4 Nb4 25.Qxa5 Nd5 26.Nxd5 Rc8 27.Ne7+ Kh8 28.Nxc8 Rxc8 29.c6 h5 30.Qd5 Rb8 31.Qxf7 Rb4 32.c7 Rc4 33.Qf8# 
1-0
```

Here is the fen,

```
[fen "5Q1k/2P3p1/8/4P2p/2rPB3/4PN2/PP1K1b2/R1B4q b - - 2 33"]
```

Comment: 4.c5 that early in the game is a mistake, as Black should follow with 4...b6 5.cxb6 axb6 and White has literally nothing to play for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My move by move analysis see below. Comments appear below the board as you play through the game. Generally a blunder rich game. White seems to like pushing pawns a bit too much, while black played too passively in the beginning. Black should have attacked the strong white center right from the start with b6. Both players neglected the development of their pieces.

```
[FEN ""]
[White "anandsadasivam (684)"]
[Black "RandyDoce (687)"]
[TimeControl "-"]
[Date "2017.01.16"]
[Result "1-0"]
[Termination "Normal"]
[ECO "D35"]
[Opening "Queen's Gambit Declined: Normal Defense"]

1. d4 d5 2. c4 Nf6 3. Nc3 e6 4. c5?! { Gives up the pressure on the d5 pawn. Temporarily gains some space but with correct play by black white will not keep this c5 outpost for long. } 4... a5?! { In structures like this you should attack the pawn on c5 by playing 4...b6 and if white defends it with 5. b4, you play 5. ... a5. In the end black ends up with a slight advantage on the queenside. } 5. f4?! { Weakens the light squares and locks in the bishop on c1. If you want to play f4, it would make sense to first move that bishop out to g5 where it can be exchanged if necessary and only then play f4. This way you avoid having a bad dark squared bishop behind your pawn chain. } 5... c6 { Better would be 5...b6 to undermine the white pawn on c5 and if white plays cxb6 (which is the best move) you can recapture with the pawn on c7. You gain space for developing your pieces, most importantly for the c8 bishop which can go to a6 for instance. After 5... c6 you don't have this option of recapturing with the pawn from c7 anymore and if black played b6 later he'd end up with a weak pawn on c6. Also 5...c6 locks in the bishop on c8. } 6. h4!? { Weakening the light squares even more. It is unclear what the purpose of this move is. } 6... Be7 7. Rh3 Ng4?! { This knight had a very decent position on f6. You should think of how to improve your undeveloped pieces on the queenside instead of moving this knight again. } 8. e3 Nf6 9. g4 O-O { Brave. Castling right into the white attack. } 10. h5 b5?! { Typically when being attacked by a pawn storm on one side, the best reaction is to either open the center or to play on the opposite side (here on the queenside). After b5 white can keep the queenside closed and also in the center there is no counterplay in sight for black. } 11. g5 e5? { This just loses a piece for nothing. } 12. gxf6 Bxf6 13. fxe5 Bh4+ 14. Kd2 b4 { Why not capture the rook with Bxh3? } 15. Na4 Na6 16. Nf3 Bxh3 17. Bxh3 Rb8?! { Nothing to do for the rook here since there are no open files here and black cannot force opening of files either (e.g. ... b3 would be answered with a3 closing the position on the queenside. } 18. Nb6 b3?! { Makes room for the knight to jump to b4, but a better chance could have been an exchange sacrifice with Rxb6. cxb6 and trying to open some lines in the center against the uncastled white king. } 19. Qxb3 Bf2 20. Bd7 Qh4?? { Blunders the queen } 21. Bxc6?? { White should take the queen with Nxh4. } 21... Qxh5 22. Bxd5 Qh1 { Too many queen moves. Improve the pieces that don't do much yet, e.g. 22... Nb4 could be an idea as could bringing one of the rooks to attack the white king. } 23. Qa4 Rbd8 24. Be4?? { Spoils a winning position. } 24... Nb4?? { Nxc5 should be played which wins a pawn, improves the position of the knight and opens the c-line against the white king. } 25. Qxa5 Nd5?? { Blunders a piece as d5 is attacked by two white pieces and only defended by one black piece. } 26. Nxd5 Rc8 27. Ne7+ Kh8 28. Nxc8 Rxc8 29. c6 h5 30. Qd5 Rb8 31. Qxf7 Rb4 32. c7? { Qf8++ or Qe8++ would already be mate. } 32... Rc4 33. Qf8# { 1-0 White wins by checkmate. } 1-0
```